# How to register new protocol URL in windows manager

Tags: linux, url

When you open a link on the internet such as `ftp://myserver.com`, it prompts you to open the link with your FTP client of choice. Same thing with `irc://freenode.net`. It prompts you to open the link with your IRC client of choice.
How can I declare a new url protocol to associate link with my binary/script ?
Or how can I add my application to the list available to handle ftp url ?

Comment: I don't understand what you want.  You can easily make a bash script that takes web addresses as an argument but they wont be a working web application.  Do you want to make a web application?

Comment: Please see `man xdg-open`

Comment: I'd like to run my program when I click a link in my webbrowser. Similar to magnet links. If you open a magnet link (`magnet://<SHA256-HASH>`) it opens a torrent program. If you open a FTP link (`ftp://myserver.com`) it opens an FTP client. Now my question is how can I create my own program that runs when I open a `abc://myserver.com` link?

Comment: You take it as a normal argument and configure your DE to invoke it when it opens a URI with the appropriate scheme.

Comment: What is your OS ? there's the answer for ubuntu here https://askubuntu.com/questions/514125/url-protocol-handlers-in-basic-ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 2):

Simple as :

```
#!/bin/bash

for f; do
    xdg-open "$f" &
done
```

Check `man xdg-open`

Comment: This isn't exactly what I'm looking for. I'd like my program to be _called_ (not open a link itself) when I click on a link as if it were a callback.

Comment: All click stuff are part of WM (window manager) configuration